# Re-render <v-select> text on data change

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

When I change the data (`CurrentClientAssignment`) using javascript, why does the displayed text not update in the v-select? How does the v-select displayed text get rendered in general?

[client v-select dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U62Ml.png)

I'm using Vue (2.6.14)

html

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@3.4.0/dist/vue-select.js"></script>
<script>
    Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);
</script>
```

```
<div id="vueComponent" v-cloak>
    <v-select label="name"
            :close-on-select="true"
            v-model="CurrentClientAssignment"
            v-on:input="onClientSelection"
            :reduce="app => app.id"
            placeholder="Select Client"
            :options="EligibleClientOptions" 
            :clearable="false"
            id="clientVueSelect">

        <template #search="{attributes, events}">
            <input class="vs__search"
                :required="!CurrentClientAssignment"
                v-bind="attributes"
                v-on="events" />
        </template>
    </v-select>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" :name="'SelectedClientId'" :value="CurrentClientAssignment.id != null ? CurrentClientAssignment.id : CurrentClientAssignment" class="dtSearchCriteria" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Typescript code

```
function Foo() {
    $(function () {
        var clientEditVue = new Vue({
            el: "#vueComponent",
            data: {
                EligibleClientOptions: [] as ClientOptions[],
                CurrentClientAssignment: 0 as number
            },
            created: function () {
                MyDataObject.getAllClients().done(this.setClientOptions);
            },
            watch: {
                CurrentClientAssignment: function() {
                    // Business logic
                }
            },
            methods: {
                setClientOptions: function (options: ClientOptions[]) {
                    this.EligibleClientOptions = options.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
                },
                onClientSelection(selectedValue) {
                    this.SelectedClients = selectedValue; 
                }
            }
        });
        $['clientVue'] = clientEditVue;
    })
}

interface ClientOptions {
    name: string
    id: number
}
```

```
function ChangeData(){
    var selectedClientName = $('.vs__selected').text() // <-- How is this getting set? i.e. ClientOptions.Name
    $['clientVue'].onClientSelection(100); // <-- Why does this change the data, but not the selected ClientOptions.Name
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us where `<v-select>` comes from, such as a third party library, or if it's custom component you need to include the component code, otherwise no one can tell you how it works.  It would also be helpful to include what versions of Vue and any relevant libraries you're working with.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I added the snippet at the top.